# Find all rows that have changed and write old-Newvalue to different table in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, checksum

Need to write to a table all the rows where values have changed between 2 datacuts.
This must be done in sql and not using any third party tools.

I can find the difference between 2 datacuts easily by using "Except".
I have not tried chksum but added a column just in case.

What I am struggling with and need your help is 
How do pull all the data out from my findings into my #Changes table?

WANTED RESULT

EmployeeId  ColumnName      OldValue    NewValue
3           MaritalStatus   Single      Married
3           Surname         Malone      Evans
10          MaritalStatus   Single      Married

**SETUP TEST DATA** 
Dummy data set up (2 Employees with Id(3,10) have changes) if you notice
employee id(3) has 2 columns changes.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Employee') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Employee
GO
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Changes') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Changes
GO

CREATE TABLE #Employee
(
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL,  
    EmployeeNo INT NOT NULL, 
    [DataCut] [int] NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Surname] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Gender] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [MaritalStatus] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [Chksum] [int] NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_#Employee] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE #Changes
(
    [EmployeeNo] [int] ,
    [ColumnName] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [OldValue] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [NewValue] [varchar](50) NULL
)

INSERT INTO #Employee([Id], EmployeeNo,[DataCut], [Name], [Surname], [Gender], [MaritalStatus],[Chksum])
SELECT 1, 1,1, N'Jo', N'Bloggs', N'Male', N'Single', NULL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 2,1, N'Mark', N'Smith', N'Male', N'Single', NULL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 3,1, N'Jenny', N'Malone', N'Female', N'Single', NULL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 4,1, N'Mario', N'Rossi', N'Male', N'Single', NULL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 5,1, N'Richard', N'Jones', N'Male', N'Single', NULL UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 1,2, N'Jo', N'Bloggs', N'Male', N'Single', NULL UNION ALL
SELECT 7, 2,2, N'Mark', N'Smith', N'Male', N'Single', NULL UNION ALL
SELECT 8, 3,2, N'Jenny', N'Evans', N'Female', N'Married', NULL UNION ALL
SELECT 9, 4,2, N'Mario', N'Rossi', N'Male', N'Single', NULL UNION ALL
SELECT 10,5,2, N'Richard', N'Jones', N'Male', N'Married', NULL

--Find all the Rows that have changed between 2 datacuts using EXCEPT
SELECT EmployeeNo,Name, Surname, Gender, MaritalStatus 
FROM #Employee 
WHERE DataCut=1

EXCEPT
SELECT EmployeeNo,Name, Surname, Gender, MaritalStatus 
FROM #Employee 
WHERE DataCut=2

UNION

--do the opposite so that we get all the rows.
SELECT EmployeeNo,Name, Surname, Gender, MaritalStatus 
FROM #Employee 
WHERE DataCut=2

EXCEPT
SELECT EmployeeNo,Name, Surname, Gender, MaritalStatus 
FROM #Employee 
WHERE DataCut=1    


--HOW DO I FILL MY #CHANGES TABLES TO MATCH MY WANTED RESULT?

 DROP TABLE #Changes
 DROP TABLE #Employee
```

Comment: If emp changed name and surname how do you know that emps are the same?

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri not sure I understand .Each Employee has a unique Id as the main identifier.

Comment: You have jeniy malone 3 and then jeny evans 8. Where is the connection between thiose two?

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri that is exactly what changed! EmpId(3) Column Surname and maritalstatus between the 2 datacuts (1,2) have changed. Basically I am comparing datacuts. Basically I am comparing "yesterdays" data with "todays" data. datacut  is what represent "yesterdays and today's data

Comment: If I was `1 giorgi nakeuri male` in datacut1 and then I became `20 jenifer lopez female` in datacut2, how can I know that  lopez was nakeuri and not someone else?

Comment: There is no way to establish a connection between 'yesterdays' and 'today's' data unless there is a key of some kind that uniquely relates a row to a specific person.

Comment: Sorry i REALISED MY ERROR ABOUT TO UPDATE TABLE

Comment: updated added EmployeeNo to identify.see updated question data

Comment: I think you should also updated expected result and use `EmployeeNo` in place of `EmployeeId`

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri Apologies!!! you kept saying it and me not seeing it. I had set up the data wrongly thinking that I had the Identifier correctly but I didnt!!!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `UNPIVOT`:

```
;WITH UnpivotedTable AS (
SELECT Id, EmployeeNo, DataCut, Val, Col           
FROM
   (SELECT Id, EmployeeNo, DataCut, CAST(Name AS VARCHAR(50)) AS Name, 
           CAST(Surname AS VARCHAR(50)) AS Surname,
           CAST(Gender AS VARCHAR(50)) AS Gender, 
           CAST(MaritalStatus AS VARCHAR(50)) AS MaritalStatus
    FROM #Employee) AS src
UNPIVOT 
   (Val FOR Col IN 
      (Name, Surname, Gender, MaritalStatus)) AS unpvt
)
SELECT t1.Id As EmployeeId,
       t1.Col AS ColumnName,
       t1.Val AS OldValue, 
       t2.Val AS NewValue
FROM UnpivotedTable AS t1
INNER JOIN UnpivotedTable AS t2 
   ON t1.EmployeeNo = t2.EmployeeNo AND t1.Col = t2.Col AND 
      t1.DataCut = 1 AND t2.DataCut = 2
WHERE t1.Val <> t2.Val
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4bb4a/1)

**Explanation:**

Here's an excerpt of the data returned by the `CTE` (for `EmployeeNo = 1`):

```
Id  EmployeeNo  DataCut Val      Col
---------------------------------------------
1   1           1       Jo       Name
1   1           1       Bloggs   Surname
1   1           1       Male     Gender
1   1           1       Single   MaritalStatus
6   1           2       Jo       Name
6   1           2       Bloggs   Surname
6   1           2       Male     Gender
6   1           2       Single   MaritalStatus
```

Using the above table expression we can easily get the expected result performing an `INNER JOIN` operation: we just have to compared 'old' (`DataCut = 1`) vs new (`DataCut = 2`) values for the same `EmployeeNo` and `Col`.

Comment: hi,i have updated the table using Employee no as the identifier

Comment: @developer9969 I've also updated my answer to use `EmployeeNo`

Comment: It does work! and MANY THANKS . let me digest it how you did it. So is this way better than checksum or except

Comment: MANY THANKS. Reading about pivot and unpivot to understand it . Wondering it though people tend to use chksum rather that your proposed solution.Am I wrong in thinking that?

Comment: @developer9969 Not sure what you mean by cksum, but as you can see what you want to do is achieved using set based operations.

Comment: sorry for another quick question.In some tables in my real db  my identifier is a composite key  EG "EmployeeNo" and "EmployeeOfficeNo" is it a case of just adding EmployeeOfficeNo as "and" clause

Comment: @developer9969 Yes just add all the keys in the ON clause